# pre-commit passing files as when using entry

Tags: flake8, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I am using `pre-commit` to invoke `flake8` with a plug-in [`flake8-requirements`](https://github.com/Arkq/flake8-requirements).

The plug-in currently requires `flake8` to be invoked in the package root, which conveniently isn't the repo root.  Per [this comment in a `pre-commit` issue](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/1417#issuecomment-620705161), I have accordingly modified my pre-commit config to be this:

```yaml
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: flake8
        name: flake8 src package
        alias: flake8-src
        files: ^src/
        types: [python]
        language: system
        entry: bash -c "cd src && flake8"
```

This works properly.  Unfortunately, the `src` package is large, and `flake8` takes a few seconds to run.  So, now `pre-commit` runs are not snappy.

How can one tweak the `entry` such that the `files` from `pre-commit` (passed as positional args) are passed to `flake8`?

Update: or am I wrong, and this works already as intended?

Answer (score 1):

`flake8-requirements` seems like not the greatest plugin -- it relies on needing to have access to your entire codebase at once so you can't really get beyond the "it's going to be slow" *and* have `flake8-requirements` at the same time.

personally I would split the `flake8-requirements` check out to a separate check and probably not run it as part of `pre-commit` (because it is so slow)

also, I noticed you're not using the official `flake8` configuration and instead ~reinventing the wheel with a `repo: local` hook.  as such you've unintentionally written a fork bomb :)

---

disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer and I created pre-commit

Comment: Thank you @AnthonySottile!  Yes the reason I did the DIY `repo: local` was so I could work around the repo root vs package root problem, otherwise I would use the official `flake8` config.  One question: if I were to break out `flake8-requirements` to its own check in CI (which I agree is a good idea), is there a command line arg for `flake8` that one can use to invoke just one plug-in (`flake8-requirements`, in this case)?

Comment: there is not -- you'd probably make a separate virtualenv with just `flake8-requirments` installed in it